# Workaround for Java not supporting unsigned

Tags: java

I have a class that has a variable named `buffer` which contains an array of bytes. I have a method called `readShort` which reads two bytes from the buffer and returns it as short. However, sometimes it returns negative values, I have no idea why.

This is my class:

```
public class InPacket {

    private int index;
    private byte[] buffer;

    public InPacket(byte[] data) {
        this.index = 0;
        this.buffer = data;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return buffer.length;
    }

    public int getAvailable() {
        return buffer.length - index;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public  void setPosition(int value) throws Exception {
        if (value < 0 || value > buffer.length) {
            throw new Exception("Value out of range.");
        }

        this.index = value;
    }

    private void checkLength(int length) {
        if (index + length > buffer.length || length < 0) {
            //throw new Exception("Length out of range.");
        }
    }

    public boolean readBoolean() {
        checkLength(1);
        return buffer[index++] != 0;
    }

    public byte readByte()
    {
        checkLength(1);
        return buffer[index++];
    }

    public byte[] readBytes(int count)
    {
        checkLength(count);
        byte[] temp = new byte[count];

        System.arraycopy(buffer, index, temp, 0, count);

        index += count;
        return temp;
    }

    public short readShort()
    {
        checkLength(2);

        int v1 = buffer[index++];
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 8;

        return (short)v1;
    }

    public int readInt()
    {
        checkLength(4);

        int v1 = buffer[index++];
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 8;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 16;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 24;
        return v1;
    }

    public long readLong()
    {
        checkLength(8);

        long v1 = buffer[index++];
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 8;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 16;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 24;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 32;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 40;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 48;
        v1 |= buffer[index++] << 56;

        return v1;
    }

    public String readString() {
        short count = readShort();

        return readString(count);
    }

    public String readString(int count)
    {
        checkLength(count);

        char[] fin = new char[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            fin[i] = (char)readByte();
        }

        return new String(fin);
    }

    public Point readPoint() {
        return new Point(readShort(), readShort());
    }

    public byte[] readRemainingBytes() {
        return readBytes(getAvailable());
    }

    public void skip(int count)
    {
        checkLength(count);
        index += count;
    }

    public byte[] toArray() {
        byte[] fin = new byte[buffer.length];

        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fin, 0, buffer.length);

        return fin;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            ret += String.format("%02X ", buffer[i]);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

So it works until one point where a higher value gets read, and then it returns it negative. (-127 instead of 129). Why is that happening and what can I do to fix that?

Comment: That's a whole lot of code you've given us--could you let us know *what* is returning -127 instead of 129?  I.e. which method or which line, and what are the values it's working with?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: There is a convenience method in [Byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-), Another thing you might consider is the [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) which will take care of many of the issues you are having. Also don't forget you'll get negative numbers as a result even if all of your bytes are positive. eg. 129<<24 is -2130706432.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method I use to read shorts:

```
public final int readUnsignedShort()
    throws IOException
{
    int ch1 = m_byteArray[m_nCounter++];
    int ch2 = m_byteArray[m_nCounter++];

    if ( ch1 < 0 )
    {
        ch1 = ch1 + 256;
    }
    if ( ch2 < 0 )
    {
        ch2 = ch2 + 256;
    }
    return ((ch2 << 8) & 0xFF00) + (ch1 & 0x00FF);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'v ebeen looking for.

Comment: You can just remove the IOException that is useless in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a `ByteBuffer` and let to it the conversation work.

```
// sample byte array 
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 0};

// wrap the byte array into a ByteBuffer instead of manually dealing with the convertion
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

// simple snippet to get the bytes as shorts
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length - 1; i+=2) {
    System.out.printf("index: %d  short: %04X%n", i, bb.getShort(i));
}
```

output

```
index: 0  short: 00FF
index: 2  short: FFFF
index: 4  short: FF00
```